# Java memory/gc issues (insufficient JRE memory, heap space, and full gc)

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am running into various issues running a Java program on a c3.large Amazon EC2 ubuntu machine with 2CPU and 3.75GB memory (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Right now I am running with the java -Xmx3750m flag. I have tried several different values for several flags, including PermSize, MaxPermSize, -Xmn, -Xmx, -Xms, NewRatio, etc, resulting in various different problems. Maybe I am overlooking something obvious, or maybe the c3.large instance just doesn't have enough memory for some of my runs.

My jobs sometimes complete with no issue, and other times run into one of the following issues:

1) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007e7a80000, 122683392, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 122683392 bytes for committing reserved memory.
 An error report file with more information is saved as:

I also tried some of the verbose gc flags, and saw the following in one of the runs:

[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 6123K->0K(12288K)] [ParOldGen: 2542552K->2546337K(2560000K)] 2548675K->2546337K(2572288K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->5555K(
21504K)], 5.1085130 secs] [Times: user=10.06 sys=0.04, real=5.10 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 6131K->6123K(191488K)] 2552469K->2552461K(2751488K), 0.0144180 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 6123K->0K(191488K)] [ParOldGen: 2546337K->2552429K(2560000K)] 2552461K->2552429K(2751488K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->5555K
(21504K)], 6.4821310 secs] [Times: user=12.72 sys=0.07, real=6.48 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 7147K->7139K(14336K)] 2559577K->2559569K(2574336K), 0.0135490 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7139K->0K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2552429K->2559569K(2560000K)] 2559569K->2559569K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->5555K(
21504K)], 4.8677750 secs] [Times: user=9.65 sys=0.04, real=4.86 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7147K->7139K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2559569K->2559569K(2560000K)] 2566717K->2566709K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->555
5K(21504K)], 4.8541370 secs] [Times: user=9.63 sys=0.03, real=4.85 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7139K->7139K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2559975K->2559975K(2560000K)] 2567115K->2567115K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->555
5K(21504K)], 4.8919580 secs] [Times: user=9.70 sys=0.04, real=4.89 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7139K->7139K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2559975K->2559934K(2560000K)] 2567115K->2567074K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->555
5K(21504K)], 6.4815400 secs] [Times: user=12.72 sys=0.06, real=6.49 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7139K->7139K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2559992K->2559992K(2560000K)] 2567132K->2567132K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->555
5K(21504K)], 4.8964570 secs] [Times: user=9.71 sys=0.04, real=4.89 secs] 
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 7139K->7139K(14336K)] [ParOldGen: 2559992K->2559992K(2560000K)] 2567132K->2567132K(2574336K) [PSPermGen: 5555K->555
5K(21504K)], 4.8817790 secs] [Times: user=9.69 sys=0.03, real=4.89 secs] 
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 14336K, used 7168K [0x00000007b1e00000, 0x00000007c9100000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 7168K, 100% used [0x00000007b1e00000,0x00000007b2500000,0x00000007b2500000)
  from space 7168K, 0% used [0x00000007b2500000,0x00000007b2500000,0x00000007b2c00000)
  to   space 185856K, 0% used [0x00000007bdb80000,0x00000007bdb80000,0x00000007c9100000)
 ParOldGen       total 2560000K, used 2559992K [0x0000000715a00000, 0x00000007b1e00000, 0x00000007b1e00000)
  object space 2560000K, 99% used [0x0000000715a00000,0x00000007b1dfe120,0x00000007b1e00000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5590K [0x000000070b400000, 0x000000070c900000, 0x0000000715a00000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x000000070b400000,0x000000070b9758b8,0x000000070c900000)

Comment: Have you tried allocating less memory? Looks like your trying to allocate every bit of server memory, but the OS needs some to run. Try -Xmx3072m.

Comment: I've tried less, and I forget which problem I ran into. I'll try 3072 now, thanks.

Comment: Just tried 3072 and got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Yeah, you need to do some sort of profiling to find out what's going on in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Better be a 64 bit operating system and 64 bit JVM; otherwise this can never work.

I'd recommend profiling your code with something like Visual VM so you can see what's going on with each memory generation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have never tried a profiler like Visual VM before; I will try it. Here is the JVM info: java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)